# separate numbers from long ints and print their char value using Arduino coding

Tags: arduino

```
long med_temp1 = ThingSpeak.readLongField(SECRET_CH_ID, FieldNumber1, SECRET_READ_APIKEY);
statusCode = ThingSpeak.getLastReadStatus();

if (statusCode == 200) {
  Serial.println("Medcine Name1 :");
  Serial.println(med_temp1);
  //lcd.clear()
  //lcd.print(med_temp1);
}

else {error();}

delay(100);
```

So there is this code. long med_temp1 is gonna receive value from thingspeak server. now the value is gonna be like 16 characters integer. for e,g 68738380827378. I wanna take 68, and separate it from the rest of the numbers, as you can see 68 is the ascii code of D. then i wanna do the same with 73, 83 and rest of the numbers and print their char value from their ascii. it all has to be done in arduino coding. can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

1. Convert in to a string
2. Read 2 values for example 6 and 8
3. 6 and 8 are in Ascii so you need to minus 48 to convert them to int
4. 6 stay for 60 so we multiply that by 10 and add second value and this is our ASCII symbol

Code:

```
char buffer [50] ;

long a = 68738380827378;

int n = sprintf (buffer, "%lu", a);

for(int i = 1; i < n; i +=2 ){
    int first = buffer[i-1] - 48;
    int second = buffer[i]- 48;
    
    char asciCode = first*10 + second;
    printf("%c", asciCode);
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its working in C but i dont exactly need that. i need it in arduino coding. as soon as i say Serial.print("%c", asciCode); it gives me an error :

no matching function for call to 'print(const char [3], char&)'
     Serial.print("%c", asciCode);

Could you please use Serial.print and arduino programming in your code. I really need your Help.

Comment: @MadhavMalik, `Serial.print(asciiCode);`

Comment: Serial.print(asciiCode);
it doesn't work! it gives a output : 5 spaces ^

Comment: Try `Serial.print((char)asciiCode)`

Comment: @xszym, variable asciiCode is of type char. casting it to char changes nothing